# Square Brackets inside of parencite-'command'

Tags: citing, brackets

I hope this problem has a solution without me giving a minimal code! If so: please let me know!

My style guide wants me to use square brackets when I 'comment' on a quote (e.g. when a word is highlighted with bold font or italics).

So I want this output:

> "This is a *bad* example!" (Doe 2017: 27; [emphasis in original])

But my code doesn't work:

```
"This is a \textit{bad} example!" \parencite[][27; [emphasis in original]]{doe2017}
```

I get that in this environment the square brackets have different 'job' to do but I cannot find a way around the problem (`[` has a different usage and TexStudio's suggestion `\left[` produces the same mistake)

Comment: Without a MWE, we must guess. But does `\parencite[][27; \mkbibbrackets{emphasis in original}]{doe2017}` do the job for you?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! I knew there had to be a very simple solution for it =]

Comment: Isn't there a (biber) command/option that makes brackets inside (round) brackets square or pointed brackets, like in math?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of `\mkbibbrackets`. Like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\parencite[][27; \mkbibbrackets{emphasis in original}]{malinowski}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]